# How do I solve this electrical circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, ohms-law

[image]

The voltage across R is Vr. I want to plot I vs Vr on a graph.

Given I = 6k mA. Now, my question is this: wont I vary with varying V1? Did I copy something wrong, or is there a way to plot this?

Comment: Yes, which is why you're *plotting it versus voltage* and not just giving a single number.

Comment: I guess "I" is the current flowing through R1. The current and voltage of a resistor are related by Ohm's law: V = I * R. You can re-arrange to get: I = V / R. So your graph will be a straight line with slope 1/R.

Comment: I suggest starting at this point and solving for I, then changing the source on the left in 1V increments to yield the transfer curve.

Comment: One question guys, as I increase V1, wont my current change as well? And if I dont know the current and resistance of the resistor (R), how can  I find voltage across R?

Comment: V1 + IxR1 = V2. I goes from V2 to V1 in this formula. That is the graph and yes, if V1 changes, I will also changes. It is just a linear graph. For V1 = 0, I = 2/R1. For V1=V2, I = 0. For V1=10, I = -8/R1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V1 + IxR1 = V2. I goes from V2 to V1 in this formula. That is the graph and yes, if V1 changes, I will also change. It is just a linear graph. For V1 = 0, I = 2/R1. For V1=V2, I = 0. For V1=10, I = -8/R1

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the resistance of R1, then regardless of the current through it you won't be able to determine the voltage across it.

However, if we assume the current through it is 6 amperes, as you've stated, and we assume that current exists when E1 is at its limits, then R1 can be either:

$$R1 = \frac{E2-E1}{I}=\frac{2V-0V}{6A} =0.333\text{ ohms}$$

or

$$R1 = \frac{E1-E2}{I}=\frac{10V-2V}{6A} =1.333\text{ ohms}$$

And the plots for both cases look like this:

[image]